# apply_filters with multiple args and multiple add_filter

Tags: filters

I'm using apply_filters to bridge the gap between plugins but am struggling with the arguments. There is one argument, an array, there are several implementations of add_filter to match apply_filters and each of them pass down the original array and add to it.

Seems that you can pass several arguments from apply_filter but add_filter can only return one argument, is this correct or how do you handle multiple arguments between add_filter calls?

I need to pass a second argument of an account ID, but it seems that by priority only the first add_filter gets to work with that argument. I plan to wrap up both arguments into a single array and pass that, so an array with an array as its first value and a user ID as its second argument.

**Edited to add example**

```
$error = apply_filters('check_for_more_errors', $userid, $error);

add_filter('check_for_more_errors', 'error_check_1', 1, 2);

function error_check($userid, $error){
    $error[] = get_user_meta($userid, 'Plugin 1 user error', true);
    return $error;
}

add_filter('check_for_more_errors', 'error_check_2', 2, 2);

// $userid below is actually $error returned from error_check_1 
function error_check_2($userid, $error){
    $error[] = get_user_meta($userid, 'Plugin 2 user error', true);
    return $error;
}
```

The above does not work as I expect or need. The filters seem to daisy chain with one the returning argument of the first one being passed as the argument to the next one.

I want both to get the $id variable and for the $error variable to be augmented as in the example.

Comment: Could you post your code to clarify your question a bit?

Comment: Edited to add an example.

Comment: Filters *do* daisy chain as you put it.  They are designed that way.

Comment: 1st arg needs to be the value to be filtered: `$error = apply_filters('check_for_more_errors', $error, $userid);`, so also fix `error_check_*` params order.

Comment: You have to return the first variable, not the second.

Comment: as @toscho says... so swapping the two arguments everywhere should fix it.

Comment: Arguments swapped over and the code is now working. My mental model is now updated and I can use yet another excellent feature of WP. I am reducing coupling between the plugins I am working on, interesting to see the solutions that WP employs. Thanks everyone for taking the time to help.

Comment: @SamuelElh Could you convert your comment to an answer to tidy up? Ta.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`apply_filters`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/apply_filters/) requires you to pass the value to be filtered in the 2nd parameter of this function (after the hook tag name)

```
$error = apply_filters('check_for_more_errors', $error, $userid);

add_filter('check_for_more_errors', 'error_check_1', 1, 2);

function error_check_1($error, $userid){
    $error[] = get_user_meta($userid, 'Plugin 1 user error', true);
    return $error;
}

add_filter('check_for_more_errors', 'error_check_2', 2, 2);

function error_check_2($error, $userid){
    $error[] = get_user_meta($userid, 'Plugin 2 user error', true);
    return $error;
}
```

Comment: I think you've misspelled the first function name as it is hooked to `error_check_1` function.

Comment: Thanks, fixed it.